# How do I detach a limb from a skinned mesh renderer during runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make it so that you can shoot limbs off of an enemy.

The limbs do indeed "die" and the right method is called.

My model uses a Skinned Mesh Renderer.

I have tried to detach it by setting the parent of the model part + its bone part to null.

The result of this was that the body part just ends up in a far away location, which may be due to that it was controlled by an animation and possibly no longer is?

I have also tried to set the Skinned Mesh Renderer root bone to another part and to null, to see if that would move it.

I am not so experienced in manipulating Skinned Mesh Renderers.

Any ideas?

[image: skinned mesh renderer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it work by making a prefab based on the same .FBX model part as the head and adding the heads material.

That way I had a completely different prefab object which looked similar in all regards.

I could then when the detachment/dismembering would occur, spawn a copy of the head and deactivate the original head part. This way the orginal Skinned Mesh Renderer is not touched but a copy is still spawned as intended. So it looks like it is being detached.